# Текст под углом

Tags: java, изображения, button, text, rotation

Приложение на андроид.Есть квадратная кнопка,на кнопку установлено изображение,при нажатии на неё поверх изображения появляется текст,как сделать,что бы тесть отображался не горизонтально,а допустим под углом,начало текста в верхнем левом углу,а конец в нижнем правом?
Для наглядности[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, кто-то забыл указать хотя бы из какой области задача...

Comment: Извиняюсь,добавил java

Comment: Я, конечно, ни разу не знаток жабы, но рискну предположить что внопку в ней можно нарисовать далеко не одним способом... Опять же, есть Андроид, а есть десктопные приложения.

Comment: bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
bt1.setText("ТЕКСТ");
}}); Можно как то программно этот угол задать?

Comment: Вы бы это в вопрос сразу внесли... :-)

Comment: @Владимир, вы про андроид или про что-о другое?

Comment: Да,про андроид...пытался,но на сайте пишет,что код написан не по правилам,может когда с телефона так